PageSpeed not resizing WebP images
One of my clients wants to switch his images to WebP format, but after some testing I can't get PageSpeed to resize them like it does for other formats.
Setup:
Rocky Linux 9: Fresh minimal install
Apache: 2.4.57
ModPagespeed version: 1.13.35.2
Enabled PageSpeed filters:
ah  Add Head
cc  Combine Css
jc  Combine Javascript
gp  Convert Gif to Png
jp  Convert Jpeg to Progressive
jw  Convert Jpeg To Webp
mc  Convert Meta Tags
pj  Convert Png to Jpeg
ws  When converting images to WebP, prefer lossless conversions
db  Debug
ec  Cache Extend Css
ei  Cache Extend Images
es  Cache Extend Scripts
fc  Fallback Rewrite Css 
if  Flatten CSS Imports
hw  Flushes html
ci  Inline Css
ii  Inline Images
il  Inline @import to Link
ji  Inline Javascript
js  Jpeg Subsampling
rj  Recompress Jpeg
rp  Recompress Png
rw  Recompress Webp
ri  Resize Images
cf  Rewrite Css
jm  Rewrite External Javascript
jj  Rewrite Inline Javascript
cu  Rewrite Style Attributes With Url
cp  Strip Image Color Profiles
md  Strip Image Meta Data

Test:
Converted an image to three different formats: PNG, JPG and WebP. Added it to a test page as follows:
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="80"
<img src="image.png" width="100" height="80"
<img src="image.webp" width="100" height="80"

However only JPG and PNG get resized, the WebP one doesnt.
From source code, using ?PageSpeedFilters=+debug
    <img src="100x80ximage.jpg.pagespeed.ic.jWiwJkYbZC.webp" width="100" height="80" < div><!--Resized image http://example.com/image.jpg from 700x560 to 100x80--><!--The image was not inlined because it has too many bytes.-->
    <img src="100x80ximage.png.pagespeed.ic.Pht8f0B3DS.webp" width="100" height="80" < div><!--Resized image http://example.com/image.png from 700x560 to 100x80--><!--Image http://example.com/image.png has no transparent pixels, is not sensitive to compression noise, and has no animation.--><!--The image was not inlined because it has too many bytes.-->
    <img src="image.webp.pagespeed.ce.WmRDo9dlUQ.webp" width="100" height="80" < div><!----><!--The image was not inlined because it has too many bytes.-->

From /pagespeed_admin/message_history
    Resized image `http://example.com/image.jpg' from 700x560 to 100x80
    Shrinking image `http://example.com/image.jpg' (177955 bytes) to `http://example.com/100x80ximage.jpg.pagespeed.ic.jWiwJkYbZC.webp' (4010 bytes)
    Resized image `http://example.com/image.png' from 700x560 to 100x80
    Shrinking image `http://example.com/image.png' (809637 bytes) to `http://example.com/100x80ximage.png.pagespeed.ic.Pht8f0B3DS.webp' (4164 bytes)
    Couldn't resize image `http://example.com/image.webp' from 700x560 to 100x80
    Recompressing image `http://example.com/image.webp' (82120 -> 95886 bytes) doesn't save space; dropped.

Summary:

JPG was resized and reduced to 4KB from 177KB
PNG was resized and reduces to 4KB from 800KB
WebP remained 82KB

Has anyone had anything similar? I can't find much online about PageSpeed resizing specifically WebP files.
Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

It says "(82120 -> 95886 bytes) doesn't save space" so it dropped compression.

That's PS attempting to recompress WebP. Read above that line: "Couldn't resize image from 700x560 to 100x80"<--That my problem. Had it resized it, it would be around 4KB...not 82KB!
